# momentum conservation related to varying mass . please help?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum

a heap of chain is lying on a horizontal table a small part of the chain is released through the hole in the table . Calculate the velocity of the chain as a function of length of the vertically hanging portion

Answer (score 1):

[We don't need to account for the mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galileo%27s_Leaning_Tower_of_Pisa_experiment)

S: Distance

t: time

a : Acceleration

g : 9.81

$S(t) = \int \int {a} dt dt$

$S(t) = \frac{1}{2}a t^2$

The constants of integration are zero since the object starts at rest.

We could just use $g$ for the acceleration or we could include some drag constant $k$

$S(t) = \frac{1}{2} (g - k) t^2$

$t = {(\frac{2S}{a})}^{0.5}$

$V(t) = gt$

$V = g{(\frac{2S}{a})}^{0.5}$

or

$V = (g - k){(\frac{2S}{a})}^{0.5}$ if you prefer to include a drag constant

Comment: The acceleration of the chain will vary as a function of the force acting on it due to its own weight ( which also keeps changing ) . i.e the hanging part.
One can't simply take it as g let alone putting a cherry on top like (g-k)

Comment: the force acting on it is g, which does not change unless you move to a different planet

Comment: g is called acceleration due to gravity  or gravitational field intensity if you can comprehend . 
Force  on  anything by the virtue of it is called gravitational force  : which is mg.